# How to raise an Exception inside a Trigger? Is there a way to do this?

Tags: database, oracle, exception, plsql

There's a situation like: If the Salary column in updated with a value lesser than it's original value, print an error message and let the update NOT happen. This is what I've written so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIG1
BEFORE UPDATE OF SAL ON EMP
for each row
  USER_XCEP EXCEPTION
  WHEN (NEW.SAL<OLD.SAL)
BEGIN
  RAISE USER_XCEP

EXCEPTION
  WHEN USER_XCEP THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATION NOT ALLOWED - ILLEGAL VALUES');
END;
```

And I get the error - Incorrect Trigger Specification

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: is it sql server or  oracle ? Make your mind up! Looks like Oracle

Comment: Oracle - sorry, I have added the wrong tag!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're almost there; you [need a DECLARE block in a trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374) if you want to declare anything; this means that your WHEN clause is in the wrong place.

```
create or replace trigger trig1
 before update
 of sal
 on emp
 for each row
 when (new.sal < old.sal)

declare    
   user_xcep EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( user_xcep, -20001 );
begin
   raise user_xcep;
end;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a12d8/1)

A few points:

1. *Never* catch an exception and then call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE; it's pointless. Someone has to be there to view the result for each and every record. If you don't want something to happen raise the exception and then catch it. I've added an error code to your exception so that you can catch this outside the trigger and handle it how you wish (don't print anything to stdout).
2. It's a minor point but I've added a little whitespace; not much. I couldn't initially see where the problem was with your code because you didn't have any.
3. You were missing semi-colons after the exception declaration and RAISE.

Read more about internally defined exceptions in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#BABBDJAB)

Comment: What does this line do? - `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( user_xcep, -20001 );`

Comment: The link at the bottom of the answer @WontSay :-). It assigns an error code to the exception so you know what error code to look out for if you want to catch the exception.