# Statement trigger is Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Say I have these three tables, Player, Thing and playerThing. Player has a name and a playerLevel, Thing has a thingName and playerThing has a playerName which is a foreign key for Player and a thingName which is a foreign key for Thing.

I want to have a trigger that after insertion on playerThing, checks if there is a playerName that appears more times than that player it refers to has playerLevel.

Like say I have a player with name 'John' and playerLevel = 3 and in my playerThing table there are three rows with the playerName 'John'. So if I try to insert another entry with playerName 'John' I don't want the trigger to allow that. I've been trying but I don't understand triggers very well, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER thingLevel
AFTER INSERT ON playerThing
BEGIN
    SELECT playerName, count(*) AS num
    FROM playerThing PT
    GROUP BY playerName

    SELECT level as lvl
    FROM Player P
    WHERE P.name = PT.playerName

    IF num > lvl
     //remove entry
END
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. I put it here so you have a better idea of what I want to do. I don't understand how I would then delete the entry that I just inserted, or if I can even do that. So yeah, I'm pretty lost I'm sure you can tell...

EDIT: 
Hey, just posting a solution for what I ended up doing if someone is curious

```
create or replace trigger numThings
before insert
on playerThing
for each row
declare
 nums number;
 lvl number;
BEGIN
 SELECT count(M.playerName) into nums
 FROM playerThing M
 WHERE M.playerName = :new.playerName;

 SELECT P.playerLevel into lvl
 FROM Player P
 WHERE P.name = :new.playerName;

 If nums+1 > lvl then 
 Raise_Application_Error (-20100,'Level too low');
 End if;
END;
/
```

Comment: You need at the start of the trigger to make a count of how many "johns" you have, to allow or not the insert. Just to save you the future trouble, try searching for compound triggers.

Comment: Trying to validate this sort of constraint using triggers is prone to error, not least due to concurrency issues. Remember that a trigger cannot see uncommitted data from other sessions. Also remember that a row-level trigger cannot query the same table that the trigger is on. At your level you're probably better off building this validation into your application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Player  --<   PlayerThing  >--  Thing
```

When I'm right you want to check, that there are exact the same amount or rows in the m:n table PlayerThing as the value of column level in Table Player.

So you have to select the column level from player and you have to select count(1) from PlayerThing where Playerid =:newPlayerID you can check that count+1 = level in a before insert trigger or that  count = level in an after insert trigger.

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE/AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name
   [ FOR EACH ROW ]
DECLARE
   -- variable declarations
BEGIN
EXCEPTION
WHEN
-- exception handling
```

Comment: Sorry, inbetween you posted code ;-(. You have to raise an exception, when trigger should not except the data. e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682341/how-to-raise-an-exception-inside-a-trigger-is-there-a-way-to-do-this