# Exception inside Trigger in Oracle 11g XE causes ORA-04088 error

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, triggers

I am learning how to write user-defined exceptions inside trigger using Oracle 11g XE and seems the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682341/how-to-raise-an-exception-inside-a-trigger-is-there-a-way-to-do-this#) serves as a good example:

```
create or replace trigger trig1
 before update
 of sal
 on emp
 for each row
 when (new.sal < old.sal)

declare    
   user_xcep EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( user_xcep, -20001 );
begin
   raise user_xcep;
end;
/
```

However, when I try this an update a record with a value of `sal` lower than the original value, I get the following error:

> Error starting at line : 24 in command - 
>   update emp set sal = 1100 where id = 1001 
>   Error report - 
>   ORA-20001:  
>   ORA-06512: at "USER01.TRIG1", line 5 
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'USER01.TRIG1'

I found from the Internet that this means a runtime error in the trigger code. But where is the problem? As the above code is from an answer written in 2013, because I am using a new version of Oracle, making the original trigger not working anymore? How should I fix it?

Comment: I think It is working as expected. You are raising an exception inside trigger which gets propagated to the triggering statement.

Comment: @KaushikNayak But when I put a line `dbms_output.put_line('Hi');` after `begin` but before the `raise`, then re-compile the trigger and then exeuting the update query again, the line 'Hi' never shows on the DBMS Output window. Why?

Comment: `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` run  update statement, and issue a rollback. It should appear.

Comment: @GreenPenguin try to add colon `:` before `new` and `old`

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan In trigger when you put old and new inside a `when` clause , `:` is not needed. It would throw error.

Comment: What's the issue here exactly? I see ORA-20001 raised (which is a custom ORA error), then it tell you (via ORA-06512, that it's on line 5 (of the trigger TRIG1, in schema USER01), which is EXACTLY this `raise user_xcep;`, which raises an exception. The trigger only does that, what's the problem?

Comment: @g00dy But I don't suppose when firing the trigger, the error as shown in the yellow box will appear. Seems like it is a run-time error of the program code to me ... while the current answer does not generate the same error when the trigger is fired.

Answer (score 1):

This happened because you need to specify *what happened?* when the custom error occurs:

```
Create Or Replace Trigger trig1
  Before Update Of sal On emp
  For Each Row
  When (Nvl(new.sal, 0) < Nvl(old.sal, 0))
Declare
  user_xcep Exception;
  Pragma Exception_Init(user_xcep, -20001);
Begin
  dbms_output.put_line('test');
  Raise user_xcep;
Exception
  When user_xcep Then
    dbms_output.put_line('-'||sqlcode||' - '||sqlerrm);
  When Others Then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
End;
```

This you can defined using the `Exception` clause, first the custom errors and then the system errors like `NO_DATA_FOUND`, `TO_MANY_ROWS` and finally the `OTHERS` errors that catch any other error that occurr inside the trigger.

If you need to stop the program you can use the `Raise_Application_Error` inside the custom exception:

```
Raise_Application_Error(sqlcode, 'Custom Error Message');
```