# Oracle SQLDevelopper SQL TRIGGER Creation Problem That I Can't Figure Out

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that manages 2 magazines, 'Elle' and 'Time'.

So if the user tries to insert a new record in the magazine table that does not match these two, the latter should not be retained.

I already have all the tables and stuff ready there's no problem in that.

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to do this properly, a friend said that this code of mine interacts with lines only, and that I need a code for the whole table and recommended that I use a **Cursor**.

Here's my code:

```
Create or replace trigger TMag
After INSERT on Magazine
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
e EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
IF :new.mag_nom!= 'Elle' or :new.mag_nom!= 'Time' THEN
Delete from Magazine where ISBN=:new.ISBN;
raise e;
END IF;
exception
when e then dbms_output.put_line('nom mag incorrecte');
END;
```

Here's a look on my tables:

```
CLIENT(CIN, CL_NOM, CL_ADDR, CL_VILLE, EMAIL, CONTACT_NUM);
MAGAZINE(ISBN, MAG_NOM, PRIX_Mois);
ABONNEMENT(AB_ID, #ISBN, #IN_ID, Months);
INVOICE(IN_ID, #CIN, dateI, State) ;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you don't need a trigger, rather resolve the problem internally by creating a `CHECK` Constraint such as

```
ALTER TABLE Magazine
ADD CONSTRAINT correcte_mag_nom  
  CHECK (mag_nom IN ('Elle', 'Time'));
```

If the provided value is not eligible for `mag_nom` column, then it will hurl as

```
ORA-02290 check constrain (<schema>.CORRECTE_MAG_NUM) violated
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use DML (your delete) on the same table that the trigger belongs to. Change your trigger to fire before the insert, and just raise the error to prevent the insert from happening in the first place.

Note that you must also declare a code number for the exception, and your logic should be if new.name!='Elle' ***AND*** new.name!='Time'. If you use "OR" then your trigger will not allow any inserts on the table at all...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TMAG
BEFORE INSERT ON MAGAZINE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    e_bad_mag_nom EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (e_bad_mag_nom, -20001)
BEGIN
    IF :new.mag_nom!= 'Elle' AND :new.mag_nom!= 'Time' THEN
        raise e_bad_mag_nom;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
    when e_bad_mag_nom then dbms_output.put_line('nom mag incorrecte');
END;
```

See here for references:

- https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-raise/
- [How to raise an Exception inside a Trigger? Is there a way to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682341/how-to-raise-an-exception-inside-a-trigger-is-there-a-way-to-do-this)